# How to add .(dot) or space or shorten volume label into 1K/1M/1B/1T in pine-script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

When I got a basic number of volume output `1000000000` in label.

- How to convert it into `1.000.000.000` or `1 000 000 000` or `1.000M`
- What `function()` can I use to convert volume output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `format.volume` formatting option with the `str.tostring()` function.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.tostring(1500000, format.volume))
```

[image]